# JS - How to stop form submission while text is empty AND checkbox is not ticked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my script so far. The aim is to not allow submission while the text boxes are empty,

```
var chk = document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByName("submit")[0];
var fname = document.forms["bookingForm"]["forename"].value;
var sname = document.forms["bookingForm"]["surname"].value;
var cname = document.forms["bookingForm"]["companyName"].value;

document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0].onclick = function() {
    textCol()
};

function textCol() {
    if (chk.checked) {
        document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById("termsText").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        btn.disabled = false;

         if (fname == null || fname == "", sname == null || sname == "") {
         btn.disabled = true;

         }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("termsText").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("termsText").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        btn.disabled = true;

    }
}
```

I know there is something wrong with the logic in the second if statement, but I cant figure out how I can allow the button to be pressed when the box is ticked, but not allow it when the fields are empty.

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!" disabled=""></p>
```

Heres the HTML for the button, which I am unable to change. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to use `,` in `if (fname == null || fname == "", sname == null || sname == "")`. You could simplify it:

```js
var chk = document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByName("submit")[0];
var fname = document.forms["bookingForm"]["forename"];
var sname = document.forms["bookingForm"]["surname"];

function validate() {
  if(fname.value == "" || sname.value == "" || !chk.checked) {
     btn.disabled = true
  } else {
     btn.disabled = false
  }
}
validate()

chk.addEventListener("click", validate)
fname.addEventListener("change", validate)
sname.addEventListener("change", validate)
```

```html
<form name="bookingForm">
  <input type="text" name="forename">
  <input type="text" name="surname">
  <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is the functionality that I need, but I am unable to change the form to have the onclick. Is there a way around this you know of?

Comment: I edited it so you don't have to change your HTML. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes thats great! thank you.I didnt know it would be best to make a different function for it.